# Twitter Bootstrap Trigger Button Issue with Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-2

I currently have 4 websites that are running on Twitter Bootstrap. When I created a nav in WP and the parent button does not have a dropdown child items the button works and sends you to the correct page. When the parent button with a dropdown is shown the parent button doesn't work, but is used as a trigger. I need that button to work and go to the appropriate page. How can this be accomplished?

Thank you!

Will

Comment: Can u show the link or create a fiddle?

Comment: Provide the code that's not working, and mock it up on JS Fiddle or Bootply if you can.

Comment: If clicking the dropdown trigger takes you to a new page, I would suggest that you not use a dropdown--there's no point.